for given matrix $A \in M^{\mathbb{R}}_{n\times n}$ prove that $\frac{(Av,v)}{(v,v)} \leq \lambda_k$
$\textbf{Question from my homework}$

Given symmetric matrix $A \in M^{\mathbb{R}}_{n\times n}$. and $\lambda_1\geq \dots \geq \lambda_n$ all the eigenvalues of $A$. prove that for every subspace $0 \neq U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\dim U=k$ exist $v \in U$ so $\frac{(Av,v)}{(v,v)} \leq \lambda_k$
(,) is the standard inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ orthogonal base of eigenvectors such that $v_i$ is the eigenvectors of $\lambda_i$
and let $k\in\{1,\dots n\}$ and $v \neq 0$ ,  $v\in V_k=Sp\{v_k,\dots,v_n\}$ then
$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
v&=\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i v_i \\[10pt]
Av&=A \sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i v_i = \sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_iA v_i=\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i\lambda_i v_i
\end{aligned}
\right.
$
therefore we get
$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(Av,v)&=(\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i\lambda_i v_i,\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i v_i)=\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2\lambda_i=\lambda_i\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2 \\
(v,v)&=(\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i v_i,\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i v_i)=\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2 >0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$
the we get  $\forall v \in V$ such that $v \neq 0$
$\frac{(Av,v)}{(v,v)} \leq \frac{\lambda_i\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2}{\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2}=\lambda_k \Rightarrow \frac{(Av,v)}{(v,v)} \leq \lambda_k$
$\textbf{My Question:}$

I solved it without giving attention to the subset U and idk how to give him space(got the joke like space sub space ) in my proof
appreciate any answer!

if someone can help and edit that in the curly bracket one of them is so much to the right

@Martin Argerami  thx for the edit!

You did actually give attention to the subspace, U when you defined $v=\sum_{i=k}^n \alpha_i v_i$. This wouldn't be true if $v$ was in a different subspace. The main mistake you make is taking $\lambda_i$ outside of the sum. You can't do that, since it's a different value for each $i$.

@Thomas Ahle whould it be true if $k \in {i,\dots n}$ ?

You need additional assumptions on the matrix $A$. For general $A$ this isn't true. The Matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and the subspace spanned by the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1  \ 1  \end{bmatrix}$ would be a counterexample.

Usually one assumes $A$ to be symmmetric. Did you maybe forget to include this?

@Maik Pickl
yeas A should be synnetruc

You are almost there, let me just push you over the finish line. As was already pointed out to you, you can't pull out the $\lambda_i$ in the sum:
$$(Av,v)=(\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i\lambda_i v_i,\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i v_i)=\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2\lambda_i=\lambda_i\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2,$$
but you can argue that $\lambda_k$ is the biggest eigenvalue in the set $\{\lambda_k,\lambda_{k+1},\ldots,\lambda_n\}$ by assumption and therefore
$$(Av,v)=(\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i\lambda_i v_i,\sum^{n}_{i=k}\alpha_i v_i)=\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2\lambda_i\leq\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2\lambda_k =\lambda_k\sum^{n}_{i=k}|\alpha_i|^2=\lambda_k(v,v).$$
Now you now that every vector in $V_k$ satisfies the inequality. All you need now is the dimension formula:
$$\dim(U\cap V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)-\dim(U+V).$$
So given that $\dim(U)=k$ and $\dim(V_k)=n-k+1$ and $\dim(U+V_k)\leq n$ we get:
$$\dim(U\cap V_k)=\dim(U)+\dim(V_k)-\dim(U+V_k)\geq k+n-k+1-n=1$$
